# When I map javascript objects, they still have Quotations marks around them?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having an issue with this mapping function. It takes an array of titles, maps their primary_causes and attached the Types.ObjectId to each item. It's strange, because it is saying the type is "object", but it has quotation marks around it, which means I can't use the returned value. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I've attached the console.log in an image.

```
function mapPrimaryCauses(titles: any[]) {
  const primaryCausesArray = titles.map(title => (title.primary_causes))
  const _primaryCausesArray = primaryCausesArray[0] || []
  const withObjectTypes = _primaryCausesArray.map(cause => Types.ObjectId(cause))
  console.log(_primaryCausesArray, 'array')
  console.log(_primaryCausesArray.map(i => typeof i))
  console.log(withObjectTypes, 'with Obj')

  return withObjectTypes
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is just how your repl displays strings. Why are you focusing on the logging? Just use your values and debug if you run into actual problems

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = "123";
console.info(a);
> "123"
console.info(a.length);
3
const b = a + a;
console.info(b);
> "123123"
```

The string `a` is only 3 characters long the quotes are just there to tell you it's a string in the print out.

Notice that `b` is "123123" not "123""123"

Also not typeof returns a string

```js
typeof "a"
> "string"
typeof(typeof "a")
> "string"
```